# How to increase number of active jobs in apache spark r 1.6.0?

Tags: apache-spark, emr, sparkr

I have sparkR application, it has multiple jobs, but each time active job is 1, how can i increase number of active jobs? Here is my code. Correct me if I am wrong. And I am using Apache Spark 1.6.0 and executing it on Amazon AWS on EMR-4.4.0

[Updated Spark UI image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3eHV.png)

[image: Configuration file]

[image: Resource Manager]

Comment: Do you have resources to run more than one task? Like more than 1 executor? As I can see in your image you just have the driver allocated to your spark. You don't have many workers for that.

Comment: I updated the with resources, but still no change in number of active jobs

Comment: I think is better you add your code snippet here. That we can se the processo to build the logic of the execution.

Comment: This is one of the execution I am trying to do

Comment: How have you configured your cluster? Are you using maximizeResourceAllocation? This flag will by design make any particular Spark application take up all of the available resources on your cluster, so if you run more than one application at a time, only one at a time will actually be able to run any executors.

Comment: Also, what would (probably) help more than showing your Spark code or a screenshot of the Spark UI would be a screenshot of your YARN ResourceManager (listening on port 8088 on the master instance) while you have a Spark application running. This will show whether or not the cluster has any more resources available for running other applications at the same time.

Comment: No, I haven't used maximizeResourceAllocation. I'm looking into it.